# Getting the return as an int from this AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, return

in my android application, i'm making an AsyncTask in a different way and i'd like to access the integer that gets returned so I can use it after. How do I get the returned value, because when i try to call myBPM as a variable, it is asking for a AsyncTask instead of an int. How would i get the returned value and store it as an int? Thanks

```
 AsyncTask myBPM = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>(){

            ...

                return BPM;  //integer value

            }



        }.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> integervalue= new Download().execute("");
```

and class decleration

```
public class Download extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer>{

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int s = 0;
    return s;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether i get your point but you could use [onPostExecute() from AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) like this:

```
private class AsyncTaskBPM extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
 protected Integer doInBackground() {

     // ...do your stuff

     return result
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
     // ...here you can access your result passed as an integer
     // You don't need to return this. You can just proceed in this method.
 }
```

}

ps.: code not tested. just directly entered here.

Answer (score -1):

```
class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
        @Override
        public String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
                   String str = "4";
                   return str;
        }
}
```

Wherever you calling this asynctask, follow below code:

```
AsyncTask<String, String, String> execute = new MyAsync().execute();
try
{
    String string = execute.get();
    System.out.println("Resulted Int :: " +Integer.valueOf(string));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: -1, sorry. `.get()` will actually **block** your main UI `Thread`, it should never be used.

Comment: Didn't face any issue of UI blocking yet, execution was so faster.

Comment: Maybe you haven't experienced it, but as soon as the `onPostExecute()` method is a little bit complex, you'll note it. Still it's a bad way of facing this.